# MySQL query is NOT executed from bash, but works from MySQL client

Tags: linux, mysql, bash, shell, query

Using UBUNTU 16.

MySQL query fails from bash, but works from MySQL client:

```
    query=$(cat << EOF
CREATE DATABASE \`${mysql_local_database}\` /*!40100 COLLATE \'utf8_hungarian_ci\' */; use \`${mysql_local_database}\`; GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE, LOCK TABLES  ON \`${mysql_local_database}\`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
)
echo $query
mysql -u ${mysql_local_user} -p${mysql_local_pass} -h localhost "${query}"
```

I get the following error after executing the bash script:

```
    CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 COLLATE 'utf8_hungarian_ci' */; use `mydb`; GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE, LOCK TABLES ON `mydb`.* TO 'user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 COLLATE 'utf8_hungarian_ci' */'
```

If I execute the printed MySQL query in MySQL client (HeidiSQL), it works fine:

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 COLLATE 'utf8_hungarian_ci' */; use `mydb`; GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE, LOCK TABLES ON `mydb`.* TO 'myuser'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

/* Affected rows: 1  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 4 queries: 0,000 sec. */
```

Please advise how to fix it.

**SOLUTION**

As @yoonix pointed, yes, the -e option was missing.

```
mysql -u ${mysql_local_user} -p${mysql_local_pass} -h localhost - e "${query}"
```

Now works well. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're missing the flag '-e' telling it to execute your query and it's interpreting your input as the database name exactly like the syntax shows in the documentation.

Comment: Do `$query | mysql ...` instead?

Comment: @yoonix yes, the -e option was missing. Please send as answer, so I can set your answer as solution.

Comment: @Zoredache I like the other solution better, because it keeps the normal order of mysql command line.

Comment: I guess, IMO the 'normal', or more common usage of the mysql command line IS to feed it queries via stdin, but use whatever works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the collate utf8_hungarian_ci part but I was able to get it to create the database without errors by omitting backslash and ticks, changing the create database line to:

```
CREATE DATABASE $mysql_local_database  /*!40100 COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci */ ; use $mysql_local_database ; GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE, SHOW VIEW, ALTER, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, CREATE VIEW, DELETE, DROP, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE, LOCK TABLES ON $mysql_local_database.* TO 'myuser'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and also added -se here:

```
mysql -u ${mysql_local_user} -p${mysql_local_pass} -h localhost -se "${query}"
```

Comment: Database names needs to be backtick quoted, because db names are using non-conventional characters, like dot. Permitted characters in quoted identifiers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html
Also I modified the 'mydb'@'%' to 'myuser'@'%' as there should be username (I mistyped it in my original post).

Comment: Changed my answer back to the way I had it as the command worked for me without backslashes or ticks.  If it works better for you with them, follow your bliss.  :-)